# Color and order of coefficients within scale_fill_manual not consistent

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-point

As you can see with my code and data below, I am trying to reorder the coefficients by demographic group, so the order is (from top to bottom): Black, Hispanic, White, Female, Male.

What I'm trying to do within `scale_fill_manual` seems to rearrange the coefficients correctly in the legend only--the colors/coefficients in the actual plot do not seem to follow. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
dtest %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = coef, y = as.factor(model),
             xmin = ci_lower, xmax = ci_upper,
             color = category)) +
  facet_wrap(~outcome, 
             nrow = 3,
             scales = "free") +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0, 
                size = 1.1, 
                alpha = 0.6, 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = -coef, xmin = -ci_lower, xmax = -ci_upper),
            width = 0, 
            size = 1.1, 
            alpha = 0, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_point(shape = 22, 
             aes(fill = category), 
             size = 2.5, 
             color = 'white',
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             color = "blue",
             linewidth = .3) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = outcome_labels) +
  scale_fill_manual(limits = c("Black", "Hispanic", "White", "Female", "Male"),                 
                    values = c("Black" = "indianred2",
                               "Hispanic" = "tan2",
                               "White" = "lightgoldenrod1",
                               "Female" = "gray10",
                               "Male" = "gray70")) +
  scale_color_manual(limits = c("Black", "Hispanic", "White", "Female", "Male"),
                     values = c("Black" = "indianred2",
                               "Hispanic" = "tan2",
                               "White" = "lightgoldenrod1",
                               "Female" = "gray10",
                               "Male" = "gray70")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Data:

```
dtest <- structure(list(model = c(7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1), category = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Black", 
"Black", "Black", "White", "White", "White", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
"Black", "Black", "White", "White", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Black", 
"Black", "White", "White"), outcome = c("ysr", "ysr", "ysr", 
"ysr", "ysr", "ysr", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "poverty", "poverty", 
"poverty", "poverty", "ysr", "ysr", "ysr", "ysr", "ysr", "ysr", 
"ysr", "ysr", "ysr", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "poverty", 
"poverty", "poverty", "poverty", "poverty", "poverty"), coef = c(0.0224673769230769, 
0.124678274725275, -0.0157007538461538, 0.328996120879121, 0.334152318681319, 
0.286053692307692, -0.252022263736264, -0.195319505494505, -0.304987736263736, 
-0.233133758241758, 0.298986065934066, 0.23503343956044, 0.391878274725275, 
0.0414132626373626, 0.167719824175824, 0.246736065934066, 0.0900949098901099, 
0.197205582417582, 0.238663087912088, 0.19849110989011, -0.235474142857143, 
-0.220236802197802, -0.265119164835165, -0.223690175824176, -0.198643747252747, 
-0.221460516483516, -0.123310659340659, -0.704752681318681, -0.139090043956044, 
0.451706428571429, 0.24867232967033, 0.248139373626374, 0.0291924879120879, 
-0.149548362637363, 0.762050692307692), ci_lower = c(-0.214028681318681, 
-0.103655473626374, -0.273158362637363, 0.159887417582418, 0.153449428571429, 
0.0967789153846154, -0.583139351648352, -0.421394230769231, -0.602876417582418, 
-0.450184747252747, -0.0486217065934066, -0.0487711857142857, 
-0.00532261956043956, -0.278972626373626, -0.0353962637362637, 
0.0344971626373626, -0.150122417582418, -0.051963521978022, -0.0029050167032967, 
-0.0624020428571429, -0.594504516483516, -0.591095197802198, 
-0.684788, -0.625167901098901, -0.433024010989011, -0.61050443956044, 
-0.36732256043956, -1.18117032967033, -0.840628142857143, -0.0308338549450549, 
0.00663712505494506, -0.132468450549451, -0.337184494505494, 
-0.355178835164835, -0.345514043956044), ci_upper = c(0.258963450549451, 
0.353012010989011, 0.241756846153846, 0.498104846153846, 0.514855230769231, 
0.475328472527473, 0.0790948637362637, 0.0307552087912088, -0.00709903648351648, 
-0.0160827648351648, 0.646593868131868, 0.518838065934066, 0.789079164835165, 
0.361799142857143, 0.370835901098901, 0.458974956043956, 0.330312241758242, 
0.446374703296703, 0.480231186813187, 0.459384263736264, 0.123556252747253, 
0.15062156043956, 0.154549703296703, 0.177787527472527, 0.0357365087912088, 
0.167583406593407, 0.120701252747253, -0.228335010989011, 0.562448098901099, 
0.934246736263736, 0.490707516483517, 0.628747197802198, 0.395569472527473, 
0.0560821087912088, 1.86961538461538)), row.names = c(NA, -35L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing data and code - can you define `outcome_labels`, it is missing from the code.

Comment: You need to convert `category` to a factor with the levels being your preferred ordering. This will also remove the need to set limits to correct the ordering in the `limits` of the fill and colour scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that via `limits` you set the order of the legend entries but the order in the plot still follows the order of your `category`ies, which if not set are ordered alphabetically. To fix that, convert `category` to a factor with your desired order.

```
library(ggplot2)

dtest$category <- factor(
  dtest$category,
  rev(c("Black", "Hispanic", "White", "Female", "Male"))
)

ggplot(dtest, aes(
  x = coef, y = as.factor(model),
  xmin = ci_lower, xmax = ci_upper,
  color = category
)) +
  facet_wrap(~outcome,
    nrow = 3,
    scales = "free"
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    width = 0,
    size = 1.1,
    alpha = 0.6,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = -coef, xmin = -ci_lower, xmax = -ci_upper),
    width = 0,
    size = 1.1,
    alpha = 0,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)
  ) +
  geom_point(
    shape = 22,
    aes(fill = category),
    size = 2.5,
    color = "white",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)
  ) +
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = 0,
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "blue",
    linewidth = .3
  ) +
  # scale_y_discrete(labels = outcome_labels) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    limits = rev,
    values = c(
      "Black" = "indianred2",
      "Hispanic" = "tan2",
      "White" = "lightgoldenrod1",
      "Female" = "gray10",
      "Male" = "gray70"
    ),
    aesthetics = c("fill", "color")
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]